# MySQL: Get latest unread message from 3 or 4 tables that are associated with eachother

Tags: mysql

Thank you for your help! I'm pretty new to SQL. And thank you for bearing with me through this long explanation. Just want to make sure I'm detailed:

I'm building a messaging system. What I need to do is retrieve the latest unread messages for 1 or more specified users, in `DESC` order.

Here is how I have the system currently structured:

A `conversation` can be created between 2 or more users and/or groups, and each user and/or group is associated to that `conversation`. Users/groups in the `conversation` can send `messages` to each other.

When a `message` is sent, it is associated to the `conversation`. Then each user/group in the `conversation` is associated to that new `message`.

So to store all of this, I have the following tables:

`conversation`
`message`
`assoc_message__conversation`
`assoc_user_group__conversation`
`assoc_user_group__message`

I have the following db-fiddle with my table structure and example data inserted into them:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/s5bU15eVSxb5TDXy2GVtUS/0

As you can see, I've put in 4 conversations, each with 2 messages - "First Message" and "Last Message".

Pretend I'm user `u-1000001` and group `g-1000001`. You can see that this user and group are in conversations 1, 2 and 3 together. You can also see that this user and group have read both messages in conversation 1 by looking in the `assoc_user_group__message` table.

What I need to do, is to be able to specify `u-1000001` and/or `g-1000001`, and retrieve the latest unread message for each conversation the specified user and/or group is in, ordered by latest unread message `DESC` (by `message_id`, not `send_datetime`). I also need to be able to specify a `message_id` to retrieve X amount of unread messages before the first request, or X amount of new unread messages after the first request (`message_id < 4` or `message_id > 4`).

I need to retrieve the following fields for each unread message: `conversation_id`, `message_id`, `message`, `send_datetime`, `raw_id`, `user_type`. You can see that these fields are across 4 different tables: `message`, `assoc_user_group__message`, `assoc_user_group__conversation`, `assoc_message__conversation`

The following is an example of what should be retrieved if I put in `u-1000001` and `g-1000001` (omitting field `send_datetime`):

```
| conversation_id | message_id | message  | raw_id  | user_type |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|               3 |          6 | Last Msg | 1000001 | user      |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|               2 |          4 | Last Msg | 1000001 | group     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|               2 |          4 | Last Msg | 1000001 | user      |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

And if I were to just put in `u-1000001`, I would get the same results, just without the group rows. You can see that `conversation_id` 1 is omitted because both user and group have read the messages in that conversation.

I know this is a complicated question, but I really appreciate your time and help!

Comment: Since you are still in the process of laying down database architecture, you can avoid using surrogate id in many-to-many mapping table. Refer: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Comment: Also, triviality of the answer to your question depends on the MySQL version you are using. Please specify the MySQL server version. Can you upgrade to the latest version (8+) ? That can make the answer less verbose.

Comment: Hi @MadhurBhaiya, thank you for your comments. I will keep that in mind of getting rid of surrogate id in many-to-many tables and delete them. To answer your question, unfortunately I have to use MySQL 5.6 because I plan to use Amazon Aurora Serverless which is only compatible with version 5.6. You had a wonderful answer to my last question which was somewhat similar, so hopefully you can figure out a great answer to this one too!  :)  Thanks.

Comment: More on the structure: `assoc_user_group__conversation` is unnecessary. Technically, a specific message can belong to a single conversation only, right ? Then just a mapping between user/group to a message should be enough to link it to the conversation (using Joins). This would be proper normalization. Moreover, you save space by getting rid of redundant data.

Comment: Also, ideally you can have two separate master tables for `user` and `group`. There you can store the "raw id" and "formatted id". This will also be an auto increment Primary Key integer `id` column in these tables, which you should be using as reference column (Foreign key) in the junction/mapping tables.

Comment: In conversation 3, only `u-1000001` and `u-1000002` exist, as per the fiddle. There is no `g-1000001` in the conversation 3

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, thank you for your responses. For `assoc_user_group__conversation`, I use it to check if a conversation between X users exists. For separate `user` and `group` tables, I used to have it that way, but couldn't conceptualize how to get latest messages/unread messages in descending order across both tables, so I figured it would be easier to use one table. I haven't deleted the `assoc_user__message` and `assoc_group__message` tables yet, so if you think it could work that way, I'm all for it. And good catch on the conversation 3! I'll update my question.

Comment: Hi @MadhurBhaiya . Hope you have a good day today. Any thoughts for an answer to this question? I'd really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: I will have some time this weekend. Will post it

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya , thank you so much :) Enjoy your weekend!

Comment: Hi @MadhurBhaiya , I hope you had a good weekend. Do you have any time coming up to post the answer to this question? Thanks.